How to map domain:port to ip address in hosts file?
Apache is running on Ubuntu in a Virtual Box guest on a Windows 11 host. I have port 80 from the guest forwarded to port 22222 on the Windows 11 host.
The network adapter is set to NAT.
I can access http://127.0.0.1:22222/ directly in the browser. So the port forwarding works.
How can the hosts file on Windows be used to map the address https://www.somedomain.local to 127.0.0.1:22222?
Or, how can I access the Apache webserver using a local domain name from the Windows 11 host?

Is there something preventing you from forwarding 80 → 80 instead? The question as posted is duplicate of many earlier threads (answer in short: "you can't do that with hosts file"), but there often are workarounds depending on the exact situation.

@grawity_u1686 I tried mapping 80 -> 80 and 443 -> 443 and that worked. Thanks.
